# Faraday's law and superconductivity

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, electrostatics, superconductivity

According to Faraday's law of induction, volts = -Number of coils in a solenoid * change in strength of magnet / change in time. This doesn't take into account distance or speed, only time. If amps = volts / ohms, and ohms is 0, it seems like amps should be infinity. If there are infinite amps, then wouldn't the alternator just generate a constant voltage without the magnet needing to move at all?

Comment: You just asked a question about Ohm's law in superconductor. The answer you accepted states that Ohm's law does not apply in superconductors and therefore no infinite current. What are you asking then?

Comment: the superconductor blocks magnetic and electric fields from entering the interior too, not just magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem a bit confused on your standing conditions, so we'll go at this step by step.

Let's start with this statement: *The magnet does not move*

From this, we can easily deduce that $V=0$

Now, $V=IR$, and we have $R=0$ as well. Thus, $0=I\times 0$, and then $I$ can be any value. (In case of a non-perfect superconductor, we have $R \approx 0$, and we can derive $I=0$, since $0=IR$ and $R\neq 0$)

OK, so you got a constant current. What of it? The current will only be able to course forever in the superconductor ring. You cannot try to draw energy off it, because all ways of drawing energy off current increase the resistance. If you add a load coil/etc, there will obviously be resistance. If you try to harness its magnetic field, the fluctuations in the field will induce a reverse current on the coil, acting as a resistance.

---

> If amps = volts / ohms, and ohms is 0, it seems like amps should be infinity.

You completely forgot the other alternative--volts can be zero instead. Then you can easily see that the current can be any value.

Comment: Now what if the magnet does move? V is no longer 0. If there were no resistance, would the voltage persistently increase as the magnet continued to move?

Comment: No superconductor is perfect??????

Comment: Even if the superconductor isn't perfect, that isn't the point. If a superconductor can last to the end of the universe before significant voltage is converted into heat, then that is good enough for me.

Comment: Also, why does V = 0 if the magnet is not moving? Faraday's law of induction does not say that.

Comment: @Waffle: (1) If the magnet moves, we get $V>0$. If $R=0$, then obviously current is infinite. Nothing wrong with that. (2) No, in this case there is a big difference between $R=0$ and $R\approx 0$. In the former, we get $I=\text{any value}$. In the latter, we get $I=0$. (Though it _can_ be zero in the former case as well). (3) I'm assuming you're using a permanent magnet. To have a change of flux, you must have relative motion between the magnet and coil. If it is not moving, there is no change of flux, and thus $V=0$

Comment: "To have a change of flux, you must have relative motion between the magnet and coil."
Is there a name to the formula to calculate the change in flux based on the relative motion between the magnet and the coil?

Comment: @KarsusRen: IIRC, all superconductors have some negligible resistance, unless they are _exactly_ at absolute zero. Not sure, though.

Comment: @Waffle:  No direct formula, but its not too hard to calculate for a small loop. Since area is constant, $\dot \phi=A\mathbf{\dot B}$. For a small loop, we consider the magnetic field to be constant throughout. At distance $x$ axially, $\mathbf B=\frac{2\mu\bf M}{x^3}$, you can differentiate this and get $\dot{\mathbf B}=\frac{3v\mu\bf M}{x^4}$. For a loop with comparable radius, it is considerably more complicated, you have to integrate the value of flux over the area enclosed by the ring and then differentiate wrt time.

Comment: @Manishearth: Superconducting is by definition zero resistance. It is fundamentally different from low resistance.

Comment: @Manishearth: You are completely wrong about superconductor.

Comment: @KarsusRen: Hmm, I removed that bit anyway--some searching showed that I was wrong about superconductors :\

Comment: Superconductors are perfect conductors. An imperfect superconductor is just a conductor with resistance.

Comment: @Waffle: Yes, I already removed that bit. I remember reading (a long time ago) that resistance _approached_ zero for these materials as temperature reduced--but that may be wrong. Irrelevant now.

Comment: Well, that formula seems complicated. Let's stick to Faraday's law of induction, where I'm guessing it assumes that the magnet is moving through each coil. I must also assume that the length of the coils that the magnet is moving through is longer than the magnet itself, otherwise I'm guessing it would just appear that the magnet is not moving, since the magnetic field would never move in that situation. So another question I have is, why is the result negative?

Comment: @Waffle: I _did_ stick to Faraday's law ($V=-\dot\phi=-A\dot{\bf B}$). I just used another formula along with it (magnetic field on the axis of a dipole); you _have_ to. I assumed that the magnet and ring were coaxial, not necessary one inside the other (in fact, the magnet cannot be in the coil if you want to preserve the "small ring" approximation to a reasonable extent). Also, I don't see why "it would appear that the magnet isn't moving" for a smaller coil--note that the magnetic field lines are nonuniform.

Comment: The sign of the result lets you know the direction of the potential difference induced (by "direction" I mean the direction of current that it entails, if there is current). Actually, you just remove the sign and apply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law (part of Faraday's law, really)

Comment: The coil is wrapped around the magnet, and the magnet moves through it. Maybe it doesn't matter how big the magnet is, as long as it moves. What is the "small ring" approximation?

Comment: @Waffle: As long as the magnet moves relative to the coil axially, you will have a change in flux. The small ring approximation is the one I mentioned before--to make calculations easy, you assume that the ring/coil has a small radius and length as compared to the distance between the magnet and the ring. This lets us assume that the magnetic field is uniform throughout the ring. Otherwise, we have to do an extra integration.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4042/discussion-between-manishearth-and-waffle <--- continue here

Comment: @Manishearth: a superconductor does not let the magnetic field in, so in a superconductor ring (a short-circuited coil) magnetic flux won’t change *even if magnet moves*, so *V* = 0 actually. A current in the superconductor will deflect the field.